# How to extract the dollar value from a row in a data frame and paste to its respective row

Tags: r

Character vector `x` contains tweets about the flights from the source to the destination city with its fare. It looks like below:

```
x <- c('RT @airfarewatchdog: Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX to Cabo #SJD for $234',
       'RT @TheFlightDeal: Airfare Deal: [AA] New York - Mexico City, Mexico. $270',
       'SOME JUNK HERE',
       'RT @airfarewatchdog: Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX to New York')
```

I'm basically trying to extract the source and the destination city with its fare from each row and storing it into another variable.

My code looks like below:

```
toMatch <- (data$City_Airport)
a <- sapply(1:length(x),  function(i) {
res <- c(i, paste(ex_dollar(x)), unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(x[i], paste(toMatch, collapse = "|"))))
if (length(res) > 1 ) {res
} else NULL
})
a <- plyr::ldply(a, rbind)
a[] <- lapply(a, as.character)
a[is.na(a)] <- ""
names(a)[1] <- "row"
```

My output looks like below:

```
row    2    3  4  5           6           7   8        9 
1   1 $234 $270 NA NA Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX      SJD
2   2 $234 $270 NA NA    New York Mexico City           
3   3 $234 $270 NA NA         SOM         JUN HER            
4   4 $234 $270 NA NA Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX New York
```

What is happening here is that the fares are extracted from all the rows and they all are pasted on each row

I'm assuming the problem here is with the paste(ex_dollar(x)) function which is inside the loop. I tried to stick that function everywhere else but it wouldn't just work.

I want my output to look something like below:

```
row    2            3           4           5        6
1   1 $234        Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX      SJD
2   2 $270        New York    Mexico City           
3   3 NA          SOM         JUN         HER            
4   4 NA          Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX New York
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have a function `ex_dollar()` that extracts the dollar value from a string (your code calls `ex_dollar()`, although you don't provide its code), then simply use `ex_dollar()` on a line-by-line basis inside the loop, rather than on the whole of the text: i.e. use `ex_dollar(x[i])` rather than `ex_dollar(x)`

```
a <- sapply(1:length(x),  function(i) {
res <- c(i, paste(ex_dollar(x[i])), unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(text[i], paste(toMatch, collapse = "|"))))
if (length(res) > 1 ) {res
  } else NULL
})
```

Comment: Yes that worked. Was breaking my head over this since yesterday while the solution was simple. I'm pretty new to R and programming as a whole. But thanks @dww  :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to extract the costs is by using regular expressions.

Using your data:

```
x <- data.frame(text = c("RT @airfarewatchdog: Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX to Cabo #SJD for $234",
"RT @TheFlightDeal: Airfare Deal: [AA] New York - Mexico City, Mexico. $270",
"SOME JUNK HERE",
"RT @airfarewatchdog: Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX to New York"))
```

The method is:

```
x$value = sapply(x,FUN = function(i){regmatches(i,gregexpr("\\$\\d+",i))})
```

This regular expression will match a $ followed by digits. If you have decimals then use `"\\$[0-9.]+"`

Result:

```
                                                                        text value
1     RT @airfarewatchdog: Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX to Cabo #SJD for $234  $234
2 RT @TheFlightDeal: Airfare Deal: [AA] New York - Mexico City, Mexico. $270  $270
3                                                             SOME JUNK HERE      
4               RT @airfarewatchdog: Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX to New York
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method for a data.frame named df:

```
# extract dollars columns as a matrix
myMat <- as.matrix(df[, 2:5])
# pull off diagonal (the data you want)
myDollars <- diag(myMat)

# construct new data.frame
dfNew <- cbind(df[, -(2:5)], myDollars)
```

This returns the dataframe

```
# set names of columns and print result
setNames(dfNew, c("row", 2:5, "myDollars"))
  row          2          3   4        5    myDollars
1   1 Los_Angeles Los_Angeles  LAX      SJD      $234
2   2    New_York Mexico_City <NA>     <NA>      $270
3   3         SOM         JUN  HER     <NA>      <NA>
4   4 Los_Angeles Los_Angeles  LAX New_York      <NA>
```